# username with DOT not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am totally new to this field.I would like to change this url

```
http://localhost/livelor/profile.php?username=naveen471996


http://localhost/livelor/naveen471996
```

Yes i did that When url like this is not working 404 Not found

```
http://localhost/livelor/vikaass.waran
```

This my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-z]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: why would it work? your rewriterule doesn't allow anything but digits and a-z. `.`. is not an allowed character.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-z]+)
```

means that just the chars 0-9 a-z and A-Z are allowed

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-z.]+)
```

should solve the problem and you can use DOT's in the username.

You should have a look at REGEX's

Comment: Do we really need to escape the dot inside  regex character class?

Comment: @Starkeen of course not, you're right. in POSIX it's not considered as a Special char, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Vigneshwarar - Did you use the full line? `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z.]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

It returns a 404 because it thinks that .warran is the file extension, and fails to load it. To fix this problem, either ban periods (aka dots) from the usernames or use % encoding (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$final_url = urlencode($username);
```

Then, when you want to decode it, use:

```
$user = urldecode($_GET["username"]);
```

That way, you'll be able to pass most UTF-8 characters via the $_GET. Be careful about HTML characters (and % codes decodable into HTML characters), though, since that might lead to some hacker issues. Use preg_replace() or something similar to get rid of those before you decode the url.

For a complete list of  % codes, visit http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Periods need not be encoded like spaces do (`%20`), and Apache won't make the assumption that `.waran` is a file extension. Where did you get this information from?